# CSS positioning is wrong in Safari and mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I have been having this issue for a while and I still haven't found a solution.  The site is located here:

[www.geoffpittsdesign.com](http://www.geoffpittsdesign.com)

...and the elements I'm having issues with are commented out.  The funny thing is that on other pages that I'm working on, there are elements with the exact same positioning rules applied to them, but they display just fine.  It's only the three nav items that I'm having issues with.  Any advice or observation would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Also, I should mention that the problem that occurs in Safari and mobile browsers is that the three icons stack on top of each other rather than assuming a horizontal spacing between them.  I can get them to change position if I specify an increasingly greater left margin.  However, these display correctly in Firefox and Chrome, and when I make the latter change, the elements go way off the page in FF and Chrome.

Comment: So what is it doing in your browser, exactly?  What position should they be in vs what they are actually in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using xhtml, therefore you need the closing tags for the list `</li>`.

Comment: If you are able you may just want to switch to HTML5. You have `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` and you can replace that with `<html>`

Comment: Thanks!  That appears to have resolved the issue.  I don't know why I had it like that in the first place; I think it may be something DW added in at the start.

Comment: No problem.  If it isn't too much trouble, you may find your HTML easier to read if you close all your tags. Then you can expect it to work with a little bit more uniformity. Fortunately HTML is forgiving. :)

Comment: Yeah, unless you are trying to do HTML5 most people don't realize that it is just `<html>` and your in. Nice that they made it simpler. :) Too bad the DW didn't default to it.

Comment: Yeah... I started finding a million little mistakes the second I posted this.  I don't know why I didn't have them all closed...  Please excuse the fact that I'm a learner.

Comment: No excuse needed, learning is a good place to be.  Keep learning and trying. :)